# Point2D returning NaN/Nullpointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nan

I have recently run into a problem that has stumped me. I am setting the location of a Point2D object to another pre-existing Point2D object. I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when I assign the pre-existing point to the new point. To explain this better here is my code and the output. The output clearly states that this first point is initialized and has values prior to the apparent null pointer. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Code:

```
private Point2D position;

public Enemy(Map map, double speed) {
    if (Panel.waypoints.size() < 1) {
        Panel.waypoints.add(new Waypoint(0, 0));
    }
    System.out.println(Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint());
    position.setLocation(Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint());//this line throws the NPE
    System.out.println(position);
}
```

Console:

```
Point2D.Double[331.0, 284.0]
        Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at towerdefencev2.Enemy.<init>(Enemy.java:36)
    at towerdefencev2.Panel.mouseReleased(Panel.java:72)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
```

Thanks,

Nick.

EDIT:

Waypoint class:

```
    int x, y;
Point2D point;

public Waypoint(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
}
Point2D getPoint() {
    return point;
}
```

Comment: `Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint()` please show relevant code of `Panel` with a SSCCE

Comment: Which is line 36 (where the exception is thrown)?

Comment: When posting an exception, please identify which line the exception is pointing to (in this case, `Enemy.java:36`). I presume it's the line with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to initialize the field `position` in your constructor and then try to print it. So the exception is thrown.

Edit:

What is `waypoints`? depending on what it is `Panel.waypoints.get(0)` may result in removing the point from waypoints resulting in a NPE when you try to access it the second time.

Comment: int x, y;
    Point2D point;

    public Waypoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

Comment: `waypoint` is of type `Waypoint` which is your own class? If so please edit in its contests into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint()); // Point2D.Double[331.0, 284.0]
position.setLocation(Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint());
```

From this two line, it is safe to assume that position wasn't initialized. You can't access(like trying to `setLocation(Point2D)` or do nothing with an uninitialized object(hence, `position`). Initialize it with:

```
Point2D postition = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
```

Then you should be able to set it to any location you need.

**About NaN**: A `NaN` value is used to represent the result of certain invalid operations such as dividing `zero`  by  `zero.`  `NaN`  constants  of  both float  and double  type  are  predefined  as `Float.NaN` and `Double.NaN`. So check that whither you are performing any invalid operation with them.

Comment: I get the same error even after `Point2D position = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);`

Comment: Please submit a working code which will be short, able to produce the error you are having and we can run in console by copy-paste, for better help sooner

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of a `NaN` anywhere in your code or the output.

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because `position` is `null` (you never initialized it).

Comment: @NickHaughton Example, please. A `null` `Point2D` *has* no values, and "printing" them doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it makes perfect sense....running this code:        
position = Panel.waypoints.get(0).getPoint();
System.out.println(position);
Produces this in the console:
Point2D.Double[NaN, NaN]

Comment: @NickHaughton NaN is a specific value that **only** a floating point (`double` `float`) can take, not anything else (ie a `Point2D`) please read up on [IEEE 754](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for more details

Comment: @vandale Point2Ds take and return doubles or floats. please read up on [Point2Ds here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/geom/Point2D.html)

Comment: @NickHaughton That's not a `null` `Point2D`. It's a `Point2D` whose values are `NaN`.